# how to parse text file, find needed string and delete X symbols after a key word?

Tags: python

A have a source .html file. It has some code. Inside this code I have blocks with links to files like this:

```
</div><a href="some-adress" class="some-class"><img src="data/62b063932513a59a02f25f37_name1.jpg" loading="lazy" width="70" class="image-products">
</div><a href="some-adress" class="some-class"><img src="data/123bdsfh5235235352366345_name2.jpg" loading="lazy" width="70" class="image-products">
</div><a href="some-adress" class="some-class"><img src="data/34f522352342342352352323_name3.jpg" loading="lazy" width="70" class="image-products">
```

Number of symbols here **34f522352342342352352323**_name3.jpg is static, but symbols are all different.

How can I open sourсe file, read it and **then delete for example 24 symbols after "/data" in all strings** of a document then save it?

Comment: So, what do you want here?  `"data/name1.jpg"`?

Comment: I want here `data/name3.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.html` file have some syntax error, so it may casuse error with `beautifulsoup`, therefore I suggest you read/write the file as plain text and do modification with `re`.

```
import re

input_f  = 'input.html'
output_f = 'output.html'
with open(output_f, 'w') as out_f:
    with open(input_f, 'r') as in_f:

        old_contents = in_f.read()
        new_contents = re.sub(r'(?<=data/)(.{24}\_)', '', old_contents)
        out_f.write(new_contents)
```

---

The `beautifulsoup` way :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
  
input_f  = 'input.html'
output_f = 'output.html'
  
html = open(input_f)
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
  
targets = soup.find_all('img')
for t in targets:
    old = t['src']
    new = re.sub(r'(?<=data/)(.{24}\_)', '', old)
    t['src'] = new  
  
with open(output_f, "wb") as f_output:
    f_output.write(soup.prettify("utf-8"))
```

---

p.s. If you want to overwrite the original file (not recommended), just use your `input_f` as the `output_f`.

Comment: I get 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\!no code\python-renamer\main.py", line 17, in <module>
    old_contents = in_f.read()
  File "C:\Users\komma\anaconda3\envs\python-renamer\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 92193: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: try add `encoding = "1250"` in all `open()` (e.g. `open(file, mode, encoding = "1250")`)

Comment: You can also try `encoding="utf8"` or `encoding="cp437"` as I don't know what encoding are used in your files.

Answer (score 1):

According to you you only want to keep something like: data/_name1.jpg, it doesn't matter exactly which bit, it can all be done using regular expressions like this.

```
import re

html = """
</div><a href="some-adress" class="some-class"><img src="data/62b063932513a59a02f25f37_name1.jpg" loading="lazy" width="70" class="image-products">
</div><a href="some-adress" class="some-class"><img src="data/123bdsfh5235235352366345_name2.jpg" loading="lazy" width="70" class="image-products">
</div><a href="some-adress" class="some-class"><img src="data/34f522352342342352352323_name3.jpg" loading="lazy" width="70" class="image-products">
"""

res = re.findall('src="data/(.*)_name.*"', html)
for item in res:
    html = html.replace(item, "")
print(html)
```

If you want to replace by length, you need to modify the regular expression, for example, like this (only 20 arbitrary characters)：

```
res = re.findall('src="data/(.{20}).*_name.*"', html)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works best for me with regular expression res = re.findall('src="data/(.{25}).*"', html)

BUT can you please modify code like that:
open source file, search, replace, write to source file. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, you need to do that.  This is not a code-writing service.  We have solved your immediate problem, now you can fill in your details.